# Electricity provider switching

Tags: switching

I live in a deregulated state where I can choose my electricity provider.  But I'm confused how this is achieved technically.

Some time ago, I lived in an apartment, and each tenant wad able to choose their own provider.  Does each provider need to run their own lives in this scenario?  If so, wouldn't that mean that any new provider must also run lines if they intent to supply electricity for the complex?

Tried Google and only got legal answers about deregulation, but nothing technical.

**NOTE** I know that the `switching` tag isn't quite what this question is, but I couldn't find anything else.

Comment: what's with the downvote?  I obviously asked my question well since I got the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically paying a power provider to show that you're not *stealing* the power. There is a meter that get's checked and if you're not paying someone, then the last company who got paid is supposed to turn off that circuit and lock it so that you can't turn it back on. Then, when you start paying someone who is a provider, they unlock the circuit and use the meter to determine how much to charge you. No extra wires, everything is from the same grid.

This is a **very** simplistic view, but should be sufficient to understand.

Comment: So all of the providers are dumping electricity into the same pool (so to speak)?

Comment: Well they dump it into their grid sector. USA has three major ones: East, West, and Texas (ERCOT). That's where they put their power. The power gets distributed and trickled down to you eventually. But yes: "Pool."

Comment: I suppose there's some sort of regulation/mechanism to ensure that each provider isn't receiving payment for more electricity than they're actually providing...

Comment: There are a metric ton of regulations for power providers including that they must produce a minimum amount of power to keep the lines regulated... but like I said "**very** simplistic view."

Comment: Well that's a prefect explanation for my "enough to be dangerous" understanding of electrical engineering.  Thanks.